# Asynchronous anchor's onClick event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, anchor

I'm trying to track anchor tag (`<a>`) clicks in React (i.e. send a `POST` request to my server right before the navigation occurs).

My code currently looks like this:

```
<a 
  href="http://example.com"
  onClick={() => axios.post('http://my-server.com', { value: 'Hello' })}
>
  Click Me!
</a>
```

But the problem is that because the `POST` request is asynchronous, the "href event" occurs before the request finish, so the request gets canceled.

So how can I perform an asynchronous event before the navigation occurs?

Comment: could you send your post request and then let the server issue a redirect?

Comment: no, I prefer that the anchor's href url will be "clean" (as is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for tracking anchor, you can use `ping` attribute to do so. check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_ping.asp).

`<a href="/stackoverflow" ping="/tracker/going-to-stackoverflow">click>`

please note that this is **not** supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Start by accepting a event into your on click handler. This will allow you to stop the navigation until the post has completed.

Axios returns a promise when you make a request. You need to wait for that to complete and then handle your navigation.

```
(event) => {
   // stop the browser from navigating
   event.preventDefault();
   // save url so that you have the value after the event was disposed
   const redirectUrl = event.target.href;
   axios.post('http://my-server.com', { value: 'Hello' })
   .then(response => {
     // handle success
     console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(error => {
     // handle error
     console.log(error);
   })
   .then(() => {
     // always executed
     // navigate logic here
     console.log(redirectUrl);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `event.target` is `null`, so in what other way can I perform the navigation?

Comment: @Scooby-Doo React uses synthetic events which get reused. This causes them to be null if you come back after an asynchronous call. I'll update my answer to fix this.

Comment: You could use `.finally(...)` instead of the last `.then`.